# Magento 2 : Custom module email template is showing Luma header and footer?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have created a custom form module, when I send email and the template showing **Luma** theme header and footer but for another emails everything loads from custom theme.

> Question : Why this is happening?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

For `'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID`

use `'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()`

Where `$this->storeManager is alise of Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`

Comment: Thanks @savan Patel,

Comment: It's my pleasure @MohammadFaizan