# Magento 2 - Sales email template override don't work

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates

I customized store email template on the theme (header, footer, and content by module), however, those related to orders (Magento_Sales) aren’t working and display the LUMA theme email.

The other email are ok (Magento_Customer for example).

I need your help, this stuff will drive me crazy.
Many thanks

Comment: How you overwrite?

Comment: in theme : app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Sales/email
for emails related to Sales
and app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Email/email/ footer.html & header.html

Comment: reference= > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272558/magento-2-custom-module-email-template-is-showing-luma-header-and-footer/272561#272561

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I didn't quite understand what to do. Could you please give more details?